# Contour integration on either side of a branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am new to complex analysis and just about starting to understand contour integrals.

There is a branch cut on negative real axis.
The contour of integration I am interested in is made up of multiple segments, of which my question is regarding the following 2 segments (the ones one either side of the negative real axis where the branch cut lies).

1. Segment A - Starts from $-\infty + i \epsilon$ and ending in
   $-\epsilon + i \epsilon$
2. Segment B - Starts from $-\epsilon - i \epsilon$ and ending in $-\infty - i \epsilon$

**Is the following right?**

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{A} f(z) dz + \int_{B} f(z) dz = \int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x e^{i\pi}) dx + \int_{0}^{-\infty} f(x e^{-i\pi}) dx$$

I am confused if there is another $i2\pi$ that I need to use to account for the branch cut jump in phase.

Comment: It's not so obvious, you do need some decay of $f$ at infinity. Essentially, you want to exchange two limits since $\int_A f(z)dz = \lim_n \int_{-n+i\varepsilon}^{i\varepsilon} f(t + i\varepsilon) dt.$ Also, where does $xe^{i \pi}$ come from? Also, $e^{i\pi]=-1.$

Comment: I substituted $z = r e^{\theta}$. As $\epsilon$ tends to $0$, $z$ tends to be $-x$ right? I guess the same as $xe^{i\pi}$. I agree the limits have to be swapped, but doesn't that apply to second integral on B as well? Is the final expression $2 \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ then? Sorry, I am more confused.

Comment: What is the original problem?